# Express.js middleware for res.send , call function on each res.send()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typescript

Currently I am making api's with express.js and

I want to send common response format like this :

```
res.send({status : 'suceess' , msg : '' , data : [] });
```

From all the controllers (functions handling my routes)

---

What I have tried :

in **someController.js**

```
someFuntion(req,res,next)
{
    // these two lines will be in each controller , that I don't want
    // want it to be automated , and minimal as much as possible
    res.body({status : 'suceess' , msg : '' , data : [] });
    next();
}
```

in middleware.js**strong text**

```
functions responseHandler(req,res)
{
    // perform some operation with req.body
    res.send(req.body);
}
```

in **server.js**

```
app.use('/',someFuntion);
app.use(responseHandler);
```

---

> I just don't want to repeat same json format in all the controllers , is
>   there any better way to do it ?

Comment: If this works, its perfect to do in this way

Comment: @selvakumar , yes its working perfectly but I don't think this one is a good way to go , inner instinct . :)

Comment: @VivekDoshi were you able to figure it out?

Comment: @Naresh, I have created one response helper file, and then make it globally available, inside that I have mixed the response, You can checkout the below answer, I have implemented almost same.

Answer (score 1):

Why not you use a file which take res and the input data to send .
Suppose you create a file

responseHandler.js

```
module.exports = function (res , data){

   res.send({status:data.status,msg:data.msg,data:data.data});
};
```

controller.js

```
var response = require("responseHandler");

someFuntion(req,res,next)
{
    // these two lines will be in each controller , that I don't want
    // want it to be automated , and minimal as much as possible
   // res.body({status : 'suceess' , msg : '' , data : [] });
    data.status = 'sucess';
    data.msg='';
    data.data=[];
    response(res,data)
    next();
}
```

You can use this approach and can better optimize it . I have used this approach. You can use two function in responsehandler file one for error and one for current data.

Comment: Then I need to , add this line to each controller var response = require("responseHandler");

Comment: I want something like middleware we are using for request handler

Comment: that you have to do , If you will use any middleware they also do same , msg you have to enter your own and data . don't make the data variable , make three parameter in response function ( message , data, status) .

Comment: I am looking for something magical , something very simple and not to repeat every where.

Comment: for trying out +1.

Comment: Did any one implemented the middleware for it ?

Answer (score 0):

This should fulfill your requirement...

ResponsePayloadProcessor.js

```
exports.ResponsePayloadProcessor = (req, res, next) => {
    res.ResponsePayload = {status : '' , msg : '' , data : [] };

    next();
};
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
app.use(ResponsePayloadProcessor);
app.post('/endpoint', (req,res) => {
        res.ResponsePayload = {
            {status : 'suceess' , msg : '' , data : [] }
        };
        res.send(res.ResponsePayload);
    }
}
```